# dynamically add dropdown menu with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement a form with a dropdown menu that has element from a database and every time i pick an element from that menu another one appears. I'm trying to do this with ajax but i have no idea how to

i know that i have to use this function to start, but i don't know how to implement the rest of it

```
function ajaxRequest() {var request=false;
    try { request = new XMLHttpRequest()}catch(e1){
    try{request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")}catch(e2){
    try{ request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }catch(e3){request = false} }
    }
    return request }
```

Comment: You added the `jquery` tag to your question. Why aren't you using [`$.get({ ... })`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting json data of menu elements in array then you can iterate and create a menu  like this:

```
let menuHtml = "<ul>";
menuItems.forEach(item => {
  menuHtml += `<li><a href="${item.url}">${item.text}</a></l1>`;
}
menuItem += "</ul>;
// Now your menu HTML is ready. It's time to inject menuHtml on DOM
document.querySelector("#whereToInjectMenuHtml").innerHTML = menuHtml;
```

If you are getting HTML from api then you can use

```
document.querySelector("#whereToInjectMenuHtml").innerHTML = yourApiHtml;
```